# How can I find thecapacity of an older model dryer?

Tags: dryer

How can I find out the capacity of an older Kenmore Advantage gas dryer model # 79801?  I need a new dryer but want a larger capacity than my old one.

Comment: You do some fairly simple math: `V=πr²h`

Comment: Is there a longer model # somewhere? Maybe on the back near the power cord, or possibly a metal plate inside the door?

Comment: Instead of spending all this time looking up the model, why not just pull out a simple tape measure and figure out the volume like isherwood suggested? Seems it would have taken 1 minute to do that vs an hour + looking for the model online

Comment: I tried googling and found this: https://www.shopyourway.com/questions/1149637 which is the identical question you are asking. The answerer stated that the full model number is **110.87980100**. Based on that and searching again I get https://www.shopyourway.com/questions/1149653 which states for model **110.87980100** the capacity is **7.0 cu ft**

Comment: Looking at kenmore the largest gas model I saw on there site was 9cuft , only took a few seconds to find them.

Comment: @EricF Post your comment as an answer and **done**.

Answer (score 1):

I tried googling and found this:

[Question about 79891 dryer](https://shopyourway.com/questions/1149637)

which is the identical question you are asking. The answerer stated that the full model number is 110.87980100. Based on that and searching again I get:

[Question about 110.87980100 capacity](https://shopyourway.com/questions/1149653)

which states for model 110.87980100 the capacity is **7.0 cu ft**